# How to display something only for the first item from the collection in Laravel Blade template

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I have a @foreach loop in the Blade template and need to apply special formatting to the first item in the collection. How do I add a conditional to check if this is the first item?

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    <h4>{{ $item->program_name }}</h4>
@endforeach`
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SoHo,

The quickest way is to compare the current element with the first element in the array:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    @if ($item == reset($items )) First Item: @endif
    <h4>{{ $item->program_name }}</h4>
@endforeach
```

Or otherwise, if it's not an associative array, you could check the index value as per the answer above - but that wouldn't work if the array is associative.

Comment: Both, yours and @gumma-mocciaro solutions work in my case. This one is shorter.

Comment: Worked perfect for me !

Answer (score 126):

Laravel provides a `$loop` variable in `foreach` loops.

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @if ($loop->first)
        This is the first iteration.
    @endif

    @if ($loop->last)
        This is the last iteration.
    @endif

    <p>This is user {{ $user->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for this!

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: GREAT! And it still works on Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 8):

Just take the key value

```
@foreach($items as $index => $item)
    @if($index == 0)
        ...
    @endif
    <h4>{{ $item->program_name }}</h4>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This will fail if the first item's index is not zero.

Comment: This will fail even if ```$items``` is not an array :).

Answer (score 7):

As of Laravel 7.25, Blade now includes a new @once component, so you can do it like this:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    @once
    <h4>{{ $item->program_name }}</h4>  // Displayed only once
    @endonce
    // ... rest of looped output
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 6):

**Laravel 7.*** provides a `first()` helper function.

```
{{ $items->first()->program_name }}
```

**Note that I'm not sure when this was introduced. So, it may not work on earlier versions.*

It is only briefly mentioned in the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade).

Answer (score 3):

The major problem with Liam Wiltshire's answer is the performance because:

1. **reset($items)** rewind the pointer of **$items** collection again and again at each loop... always with then same result.
2. Both **$item** and the result of **reset($item)** are objects, so **$item == reset($items)** requires a full comparison of its attributes... demanding more processor time.

A more efficient and elegant way to do that -*as Shannon suggest*s- is to use the Blade's **$loop** variable:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    @if ($loop->first) First Item: @endif
    <h4>{{ $item->program_name }}</h4>
@endforeach
```

If you want to apply a special format to the first element, then maybe you could do something like (using the ternary conditional operator **?:** ):

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    <h4 {!! $loop->first ? 'class="special"': '' !!}>{{ $item->program_name }}</h4>
@endforeach
```

Note the use of `{!!` and `!!}` tags instead of `{{` `}}` notation to avoid html encoding of the double quotes around of ***special*** string.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

if you need only the first element you can use `@break` inside your `@foreach` or `@if`.see example:

```
@foreach($media as $m)
    @if ($m->title == $loc->title) :
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="images/{{ $m->img }}">
          
        @break
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by this way.

```
collect($users )->first();
```

Answer (score -3):

To get the first element of a collection in Laravel, you can use :

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    @if($item == $items->first()) {{-- first item --}}
        <h4>{{$item->program_name}}</h4>
    @else
        <h5>{{$item->program_name}}</h5>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: The question is about the Blade templating system; not Laravel itself.

Comment: The question is about LARAVEL Blade. Read the question

Comment: Blade is the template system included in Laravel. OP isn’t asking about Laravel as a whole but rather Blade itself. Your answer doesn’t address OP’s question, as you can guess from the downvotes and the others’ answers.

Comment: The question is :
How to display something only for the first item from the collection in Laravel Blade template.
There is LARAVEL in the question !!!

Comment: There is "laravel blade" in the question. Not "laravel" only.

Comment: The answer with best note quotes Laravel 5.3 !